# Android Studio line break not showing in the layout preview how to fix it?

Tags: android

here is my code

```
<string name="ark_fear_evolved2015_2"><b>ARK: Fear Evolved</b> was an <i>ARK: Survival Evolved</i> Halloween event.\n\n<b>Start date:</b> October 28th, 2015\n<b>End date:</b> November 5th, 2015</string>
```

On the phone it shows everything perfectly fine but when I'm on Android Studio it doesn't render the way its supposed to be.[Here is a picture of the preview not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DJfc.png)

I've tried everything I could

Comment: If you gonna use HTML, use `<br>` instead of `\n`

Comment: in the layout preview it still doesn't show its working. it has to be something in Android Studio that is causing it to not show the line breaks in preview.

Comment: So using this in strings.xml breaks the code for so reason but it use to work just fine <b></b> <i></i>